# Attaching an Html style sheet to an Angular app

Tags: html, css, angular, stylesheet

I'm making an Angular web app to replace an existing website. said existing website already has a style sheet, and since Angular allows me to pretty much copy and paste my front end code directly into the new app i want to use the same style sheet. but its nearly 22,000 lines long so putting it inline is out of the question.

i added it to my file directory and added it to my **app.component.ts**
like so:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.BigHugeMess.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
    title = 'app';
}
```

this method causes my app to fail when attempting to run. saying that:

> ./app.color.ts couldn't be found in the current directory

but i have never created a color.ts.

what would be the best way to tie this style sheet file i have to my Angular app? because the way i'm using obviously isn't working.

Comment: The code you have posted looks correct. Consider searching through your app for `app.color.ts` to see if it is indeed defined somewhere.

Comment: Do you have any other component, service, class, etc in your project?

Comment: Check all the file for that error

Comment: Are you using angular cli

Comment: Because I can: there is no such thing as a "Html stylesheet" or "a style sheet in HTML". It's CSS or it's not.

Comment: @Rob sorry, its a css file with <!DOCTYPE html>. i typed that confusingly.

Answer (score 3):

If you're not going to break down the CSS into more manageable chunks by component, and you're just look for a quick and dirty solution, you could link the CSS file directly into your index.html file with a standard stylesheet ref:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/app.BigHugeMess.css">
```

Then just put the file in a css directory at the root of your project.

I would strongly suggest breaking the styles down and associating styles with the appropriate components. 22,000 lines of CSS is pretty massive, and I'd be surprised if there's not a lot of redundant code in there. In order to build an app that's maintainable, you're going to have to get a handle on that, and at the start is the best time.

As to why the file is throwing an error as it sits, there maybe something in your web pack config that's processing css files, or expecting scss files and not handling the css file correctly, it's hard to say without seeing more of your project.

Comment: i'm using the big file first to ensure that in the basic my app will function. then i will start cutting through the styles and assigning each to its own component. its a big chunk of legacy code that i will need to edit as part of renovating this website. so would you suggest that ii break it into a collection of assets that i can link to the components that need it? (ex. color.css, fonts.css, ect...)

Comment: It's going to be different for every project. I would look for base styles that define rules for everything and migrate them into a app.css file, and then look for sections of the css that are specific to a page or section, and see if you can break those off. Massive css files usually exist because the coder treated every page as an exception and added page specific styles rather than use fewer more general styles that enforced consistency across the project. Cleaning things up will be a lot of work, but try to understand why styles are there and that will help you find a place to put them.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to add the stylesheet to `angular-cli.json` `styles` array to be referenced directly by the angular app .

```
"styles": [
        "../location of your custom stylesheet",
        "styles.css"
      ],
```

But as pointed by @Stephen you should consider breaking your style sheet to multiple files as then you can use multiple Angular Features like `View Encapsulation` etc .. and also modifying style sheets up and down the hierarchy